# Wordpress portfolio posts: media not displaying if several images

Tags: posts, images, uploads, import

A friend in need asked me to fix his wordpress website; I am new to it.
The website is quite old. He used portfolio posts; it displays just fine when there is only one image selected, but there is a problem when several images are uploaded to the post.

I do not see any particular plugins installed (only "Link Manager" & "Simple Page Ordering" activated). From what I can see online, I feel like I am going to have to install a new plugin and do it all from scratch; maybe what they did is obsolete...

But if any of you have an idea to fix this in a quicker way, I would be very thankful!

(UI with only one image uploaded to portfolio post)
[image]

However, with several images, only the text displays, no images (all are images, no video, and all are roughly the same size; the problem only happens because there is more than 1)

(backoffice)
[image]

(UI)
[image]